# ReactJS loosing reference of an element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus, setfocus

I am forcing element to be focused like this

```
/**focusing the element if the element is active */
    componentDidUpdate() { 
        console.log(this.activeElementContainer);
        if(this.activeElementContainer!==undefined && this.activeElementContainer!==null) {
            /** need to focus the active elemnent for the keyboard bindings */
            this.activeElementContainer.focus();            
        }
    }
```

My render has conditional rendering the elements are being rendered dynamically from the array,

Let say I have one element in div and I am adding another from the toolbox. In that case I need to focus the last element I dragged.

```
render() {

let childControl= <span tabIndex="-1" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: htmlToAdd}}></span>;
if(this.props.activeItem){

childControl=<span  ref={ (c) => this.activeElementContainer = c } 
tabIndex="0"  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: htmlToAdd}}></span>

}
//later I ma using childControl to array and it works fine.
```

The logs says, first time it works fine

But, second time the this.activeElementContainer is `undefined`

Is there any alternative way or possible solution to this?

The thing is I need to focus only one element at the time.

Remember: Activecontrol has too many things to do like it can have right click menu, drag etc. so, I need to render it separately.

Comment: try changing ref to `ref={ c => ( this.activeElementContainer = c) }`

Comment: I changed my code little bit. now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this one github:

> This is intended (discussed elsewhere) but rather unintuitive
>   behavior. Every time you render:
>
> `<Value ref={(e) => { if (e) { console.log("ref", e); }}} />` You are
>   generating a new function and supplying it as the ref-callback. React
>   has no way of knowing that it's (for all intents and purposes)
>   identical to the previous one so React treats the new ref callback as
>   different from the previous one and initializes it with the current
>   reference.
>
> PS. Blame JavaScript :P

[Source](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6249#issuecomment-195412139)

I changed my code to

```
<span id={this.props.uniqueId} ref={(c)=>
                    {if (c) { this.activeElementContainer=c; }}
                } tabIndex="0"   dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: htmlToAdd}}></span>
```

Adding if was the real change. now, it has a ref.

For others who face this problem:
I need to write custom function too, in the **componentDidUpdate**  I am still getting old reference,

```
ref={(c)=>{if (c) { this.activeElementContainer=c; this.ChangeFocus(); }}
```

Adding this was the perfect solution for me